# Android Instrumentation Test without target-package

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I have a android library that dependence on logcat.

I want to have an instrumentation test for this library.

However, the instrumentation require me to specify a target-apk to instrument. But, I don't need/have one.

So, what is the proper way to write test in this case?

Comment: Normally I'd either use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) to run against a localised Android framework as part of a standard JUnit test, or create a "dummy" test app that uses the library.

Comment: Yes, I thought about dummy test app.

Comment: how does the Robolectric test with localised Android Framework works exactly?

Comment: In short, Robolectric is a test runner that allows you to run standard JUnit tests against a modified version of the Android Framework locally on your own PC. Effectively you can run tests that require Android-specific classes such as `Context` without needing an actual Android device. It does have some limitations, for UI tests you're still better off running connected `androidTest`s, but for your requirements it should be good.